# static interference coming from speakers

Tags: desktop-computer

I get buzzing interference on my speakers.  They are not wireless, the left and right speaker are on the same lead that plugs into the back of my computer.  What could be causing the noise and can I eliminate it without replacing the speakers? The lead is not close to any power cords, also have moved speakers to different locations with no luck, still have interference bleeding through. Thank you

Comment: Issue with how they are powered and poor shielding, or the signal line from speaker out to the speakers is picking up interference being next to electrical cables, etc.

Comment: Does the buzz is only heard when speakers are connected to the computer? Have you tried to connect some other speakers? To connect these speakers to a some other audio source (e. g. a smartphone)? Change an audio cable?